# Find all keys in an array that are not equal to zero

Tags: php, arrays, key

How can I setup the function **array_keys** to return all keys in my array that have values that are not equal to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by [filtering the array](http://php.net/array_filter) first:

```
$results = array('ab' => 0, 'ba' => 53, 'pl' => 23, 'ct' => 0);

$non_zero = array_keys(array_filter($results, function($item)
{
    return $item !== 0;
}));

// Value of $non_zero:
//   array('ba', 'pl')
```

Comment: Actually no need for the anonymous function.  Zero values are falsy, and will be removed by default with `array_filter()`

Comment: @Michael:  I wasn't sure if Djacksway wanted strict comparison or not, so that's why I supplied a callback.

Comment: @Tim Cooper, Im pretty new to php Tim how would I call this function assuming my array is $results.  I know I have to define it then call it but an still slightly confused.  Thanks,

Comment: @Djacksway:  I've just updated my answer which should help you understand how to implement the code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, which is what I did I am just getting a parse error for a T_FUNCTION.  I will have to do some more digging.  Thanks

Comment: @Djacksway:  That error means your version of PHP doesn't support [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).  I would recommend upgrading PHP, however if that is not an option for you, simply change the anonymous function to a regular one.